# entities-only intents in NLP engines (LUIS/Wit/others)?

Tags: nlp, wit.ai, azure-language-understanding

Say I need to build a simple order status bot. I wonder whats the best way to form the intents:

I could have 2 intents like this

a. "Hi, I'd like to know the status of my order", "where's my order" etc. - intent QuerySTatus

b. "Joe Levi, +16463730044", "6463730044" etc - intent orderDetails - entities phone number, name

or, just one intent:

a.  "Hi, I'd like to know the status of my order", "where's my order", "what is the status of Joe Levi order", "when order for phone 16463730044 ready" etc. - intent QueryStatus, with entities phone number, name

If I'm going with 2 intents, I guess the sentences like: "please let me know the status of the order for Joe Levi of phone #12345678" - would fall into intent 1 (with entities extracted). but then, would there be enough differentiation between the two intents?

If I'm going with 1 intent, how would the engine treat utterances like  "Joe Levi, +16463730044"  (which could be uttered as a reply when the bot asks "whats your name and number?") we have a reply with only entities.

is there a third way? whats best for Wit? for LUIS?

thanks!

Lior

Answer (score 3):

For LUIS, I suggest going with the one intent option.
You can also check the new Actions feature in LUIS under intents, it links entities (as parameters) to intents.